# How to write a protagonist in 1st POV, who is talkative?

Tags: dialogue, description, pov

My character is very talkative. As the narrator, how is she to balance her talkativeness in dialogue, narration, and description without making it boring, too long, or make it seem like she's dumping too much information?

Comment: Related: [Pitfalls for writing a talkative character?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/23886/34330)

Answer (score 2):

**You can make this very interesting, if it fits your writing style**

Traditionally, 1st POV characters tend to think a lot, but speak little. If your character is talkative, you can make her [Thinking Out Loud](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThinkingOutLoud) or even do [Audience Monologues](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AudienceMonologue) (TV Tropes warning) all the time, and it would look natural for her. No more beating around the bush with descriptions and reflections - when you, as an author, need to tell something to the audience, your character can literally speak that out loud.

Comment: If done well, I could envision the talkative POV breaking the fourth wall as if the protagonist was telling the reader a story face-to-face. Dunno, maybe a mix of old-time live storytelling, modern stand-up comedy, and ironic remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

> On September 29th, at 7:38 AM, I was struck by a blue SUV while
> crossing the street.  The SUV had slid on the newly-fallen snow and
> failed to stop. I died 2 1/2 minutes later, 23 minutes before the
> ambulance arrived.

Example 2:

> Janice always told me to be careful crossing the street.  I died
> crossing the street, you know.  It was a Tuesday.  The car slid on the
> snow, in September!  It never snows in September, but it did that day.  What are the odds.

When you're telling a story in 1st Person, your character is necessarily saying something.  The impression that the narrator is talkative comes through in what details you emphasize (or just include), and the style of presentation.  You're not necessarily saying more.

In general, in 1st Person narration, you're revealing something about the character based on what the character thinks is important enough to include, and how formally or casually those things are mentioned.  It's another layer where tone and character can be defined.  Even distant, clinical language will communicate something.  Chattiness will communicate something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make her an interesting person to listen to.

This depends a lot on your style, but a talkative character is going to be as boring or interesting as her manner of talking.